# make a text file into a list

Tags: list, file, python-3.6

This is what my text file consists of:
"file1
file2"

So far this is my code:

```
def create_filenames_list(filename):
    filenames_list = []
    file = open('input.txt', "r").readlines()
    for line in file:
            filenames_list = line

    return filenames_list.split()
def main():
    filenames_list = create_filenames_list('input.txt')
    print(filenames_list)
```

The Output I got:
"file2"
What I expected is:
['file1', 'file2']

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_filenames_list(filename):
filenames_list = []
file = open('input.txt', "r").readlines()
for line in file:
        filenames_list.append(line)

return filenames_list
def main():
    filenames_list = create_filenames_list('input.txt')
    print(filenames_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    filenames_list = line
```

(which *overwrites* the *list* `filenames_list` two times with a `string`, so it will in the end contain only the *latest* one - `"file2"`)

use

```
    filenames_list.append(line)
```

to append to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file had each filename on a separate line then 'file.readlines()' would readily generate the list that you wanted.

Also, you don't need to read the entire file into a variable (file = open('input.txt', "r").readlines()) before looping through it. You can loop directly over the file object (f = open('input.txt',"r")).

Do all of your filenames have to be on a single line as they appear to be? If so you can simply get the first line and then split it into the list.

```
filenames_list = open('input.txt',"r").readline().split()
```

In your code the 'file' variable is already a list of each line in your text file. The loop following is looping over that list and ultimately returns only the last line in the file. Finally, you return a list of the space-separated values from only that final line of the file.

Again, if you place each filename on a separate line of the file your code can be very much simplified:

```
def create_filenames_list(filename):
  return open(filename,"r").readlines()

def main():
  filenames_list = create_filenames_list('input.txt')
  print(filenames_list)
```